# Changing pixel values by the average of neighbours in raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapping

I have a raster with values in each pixels. I need to change each pixel by the average of surrounding pixels. For example in the first row first column , the pixel  value will be replaced by average of the first four cells, but in the second row second column since it is surrounded by neighbouring 8 cells the the value will be the average of nine cells.

How to do this using raster calculator?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/focal-statistics.htm

Comment: Hi..am not much aware of python script.Any string form of expressions available so that it can  be directly applicable in raster calculator?

Comment: To use this tool you need 0 knowledge of python.

Comment: OutRas = FocalStatistics(InRas1, NbrRectangle(3,3,MAP), "SUM", "") where should i apply this sir , in raster calculator?

Comment: For example the value of  first pixel will be replaced by the average of its surrounding three and the pixel concerned pixels .The edge pixels except the corners the value should change to the average of 6 pixels including the concerned,For rest the pixel value should change to the average of 9 pixels (surrounding 8 and the pixel concerned). all this should work simultaneously if not the value of one output will b the input for the second process..this may change the entire original data and calculations.

Comment: See my answer below. Minus one BTW for showing interest in your own question with 5-10 days interval.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in terms command line GIS. In ArcGIS it's mostly done through graphic user interface. Open ArcGIS, go Ctrl+F to open search window. Pick "Tools" and type "focal statistics":

[image]

Click on bold blue line to open dialogue to be populated:

[image]

However if you insist on raster calculator you can go:

[image]

after bringing your raster to open map document. Read about environment settings of above tool to avoid ridiculous results.